# Dynamics Plugin throwing "Could not load file or assembly" error

Tags: plugins, microsoft-dynamics, filenotfoundexception, ilmerge

I have a Dynamics365 Plugin which references a Nuget written by me. The build and the registration of the Plugin works and also the merge of all Libraries worked.

When the Plugin is triggered I get the following error:

```
Error 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'CustomNuget.Xrm.Common.XYZ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The Assembly mentioned in the above error is the Nuget included in the Plugin.

What I know for sure is that this exception is thrown from within a Method which is contained in the above mentioned Assembly (Nuget).

When I check the plugin assemby with ILSpy everything looks ok.

How can this be that an exception is telling me the assembly was not found but the error was thrown exactly from this assembly??

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: We need some more specifics, like namespace, assembly, method, etc for some clue.. to see what’s going on

Comment: I understand that there are not enough details. Its actually difficult to extract more details to make it more understanable. there are many parts involved but I will see if I can provide some more info in that. I just thought that maybe one had already a similar phenomenon. Il come back to my question soon.